# javascript - sum of values on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm modifying a draft website which is basically mde by storing data in local storage and fetching and rendering it. On the **cart.html** page input are created dynamically, depending upon how many packages are added in the cart.

There are 2 prices, one which is package's price (works totally fine) and the other one is **Total price of all the items in cart, which doesn't seem to update and adds on values to the previous value.** I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help would be great!

**I'm also attaching stackblitz to get better understanding of my application. Please readme if you want instructions**

**cart.html**

```
        <div class="totalPrice">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Price</td>
                    <td id="totalPriceCount" data-total=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**JS:** (Don't really have idea how to achieve)

```
$(".myInput").on('input', function () {
            varCurrentVal = this.value;
            if (varCurrentVal == 0) {
                return;
            }
            var closestSibAttr = $(this).parent().parent().find("#quantityBasedPrice").attr("data-val");
            $(this).parent().parent().find("#quantityBasedPrice").html(varCurrentVal * closestSibAttr).attr("data-total", varCurrentVal * closestSibAttr);

// code to update #totalPriceCount to sum all the values into the Total Price
        })
```

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-8cynxp?file=turkey.html

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().find("#quantityBasedPrice")` must be the same as `$("#quantityBasedPrice")`. If it’s not, you have invalid HTML.

Comment: @Sebastian that’s updating the closest price on input change. It works fine! I want to update the total price at the end, that I am unable to update

Comment: where is and what is `#quantityBasedPrice`, `varCurrentVal` and more ? your  question is incomplete !  READ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example